# Descargar o Generar Txt con ResponseEntity en Java

Tags: java, spring

estoy desarrollando un método que descarga un txt, sin especificar su fichero de descarga, solo al final del método agrego nombre del archivo, ya que el método es tipo ResponseEntity.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/factura/logs/{idArchivo}/txt", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFileLogsTxt(@PathVariable(name = "idArchivo") Integer 
idArchivo) throws CfdiServiceException{

    List<LogsPACsBean> result = new ArrayList<LogsPACsBean>();
    result = logsPACService.logsPorIdArchivo(idArchivo);
    String ruta = "";
    File file = new File(ruta);

    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(result.);
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("ERROR: ", e);
        throw new CfdiServiceException(ErrorEnum.EXC_OPER_NO_EXITOSA);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE))
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + result.getNameFile());
}
```

Eh investigado y solo encuentro métodos que agregan el fichero antes de. Me estoy basando en este método que descarga un excel.

```
public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFileLogs(@PathVariable(name = "idArchivo") Integer idArchivo) throws CfdiServiceException{
    ArchivoFacturaBean archivo = facturacionService.getArchivoById(idArchivo);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Workbook workbook = xlsService.reproceso(idArchivo);
    if(workbook==null) {
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
    try {
        workbook.write(stream);
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("ERROR: ", e);
        throw new CfdiServiceException(ErrorEnum.EXC_OPER_NO_EXITOSA);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE))
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + archivo.getNombreArchivo().replace(".", "_R.") + "\"")
            .body(new ByteArrayResource(stream.toByteArray()));
}
```

Comment: Este código te da error o no funciona?

Comment: El que se desarrolló para excel si funciona, pero el que requiero yo para el txt esta basado en la mayoría de los que se encunetran en internet, mas que nada me interesa como agregar la ruta de descarga, pues lo que se escribirá en el txt se puede realizar facilmente

Comment: Si pero el txt no te funciona o te da error?

Comment: no, me funciona

Comment: Entonces modifica tu pregunta con lo que deseas realizar especificamente porque si te funciona, no hay un problema claro al que se pueda ayudar.

Comment: Disculpa José, un error, no, no me funciona, agregué coma, disculpa, no me funciona